# cmake on macosx maverick, how to force /usr/include to be included

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, include-path

I am working on a macosx 10.9 with a fresh update of xcode and I have done xcode-select --install. 
I have a C++ file that use the header GL/glew.h and stdio.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

Glew is installed in /usr/include.

```
$ ls /usr/include/GL
glew.h  glxew.h wglew.h
```

stdio.h is also in the /usr/include but a locate shows that it is present in many folders including :

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/

If I try to compile the code without specifying the /usr/local include path, I get

```
 fatal error: 'GL/glew.h' file not found
 #include <GL/glew.h>
```

Notice that stdio seems to have been included successfully. 
If I add  -I/usr/include  to g++ in the command line the compilation is successful.

Now, I have a cMakeList.txt that add /usr/include, like that :

```
 include_directories ( /usr/include/)
```

but in the resulting makefile the -I/usr/include/ does not appears and the compilation failed just as before.

My current workaround is a symbolic link to /usr/include/ named /usr/include2, and then include that directory. With that configuration the -I/usr/include2 is added to the makefile and everything works well. However it is ugly and I am missing something there.

My guess is that /usr/include should be included by default thus cmake skips it, however x-code use a different default include path (where incidentally stdio.h is also found).

Does anyone knows how to either :

1. fix xcode/g++ so that it (also) use by default /usr/include
2. force cmake to literally include /usr/include

I hope I have included enough information because it is my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think `cmake` or `xcode` change their behaviour and now include directories automatically substitute from `/usr/include/` to `/.../Xcode.app/.../SDKs/MacOSX/usr/include`
(it's working [earlier](https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/commit/cbd230c03256c3f987f8ce0829398e799c62693a) for me). As a workaround you can add compiler flags explicitly:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/include")
```

note that in your [case](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindGLEW) you can use `find_package`:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In XCode you should be able to add /usr/include to your search paths in your projects Build Settings:

[image: XCode Search Paths]

Comment: it's not quite comfortable to hack xcode project itself if you're using cmake as generator

Comment: @ruslo — op wrote `"fix xcode/g++ so that it (also) use by default /usr/include"` — which is my answer.